# Token Caching in Asp.Net Webforms is not working for Azure Ad?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, access-token

I want to cache the token and then access it from the webform. For that I have my code like below

Startup.cs

```
namespace WebFormB2B
{
    public class Startup
    {
    // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD.
    string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

    // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in.
    string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];

    // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or 'common' for multi-tenant)
    static string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];
    public const string BasicSignInScopes = "openid profile offline_access";

    // Authority is the URL for authority, composed by Azure Active Directory v2 endpoint and the tenant name (e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0)
    string authority = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"], tenant);

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure OWIN to use OpenIdConnect 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = BasicSignInScopes + " "+"User.Read",
                // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
                // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter 
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                },
                // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                }
            }
        );// ;
    }
    private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context)
    {
        // Upon successful sign-in, get the access token and cache it by using MSAL.
        IConfidentialClientApplication clientApp = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication( );
        AuthenticationResult result = await clientApp.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(new[] { "User.Read" }, context.Code).ExecuteAsync();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Handle failed authentication requests by redirecting the user to the home page with an error in the query string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private Task OnAuthenticationFailed(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        context.Response.Redirect("/?errormessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

}

MSALAppbuilder

```
public static class MsalAppBuilder
{        // The Client ID is used by the application to uniquely identify itself to Azure AD.
  static  string clientId = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];

    // RedirectUri is the URL where the user will be redirected to after they sign in.
    static string redirectUri = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RedirectUri"];

    // Tenant is the tenant ID (e.g. contoso.onmicrosoft.com, or 'common' for multi-tenant)
    static   string tenant = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Tenant"];

    static string Authority = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}{1}", "common", "/v2.0");  //System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Authority"];
    public static string GetAccountId(this ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
    {
        string oid = claimsPrincipal.GetObjectId();
        string tid = claimsPrincipal.GetTenantId();
        return $"{oid}.{tid}";
    }

    public static IConfidentialClientApplication BuildConfidentialClientApplication()
    {
        IConfidentialClientApplication clientapp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
              .WithClientSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
              .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
              .WithAuthority(new Uri( Authority))
              .Build();

        // After the ConfidentialClientApplication is created, we overwrite its default UserTokenCache serialization with our implementation
        IMsalTokenCacheProvider memoryTokenCacheProvider = CreateTokenCacheSerializer();
        memoryTokenCacheProvider.Initialize(clientapp.UserTokenCache);
        return clientapp;
    }

    public static async Task RemoveAccount()
    {
        IConfidentialClientApplication clientapp = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
              .WithClientSecret("XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
              .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
              .WithAuthority(new Uri( Authority))
              .Build();

        // We only clear the user's tokens.
        IMsalTokenCacheProvider memoryTokenCacheProvider = CreateTokenCacheSerializer();
        memoryTokenCacheProvider.Initialize(clientapp.UserTokenCache);
        var userAccount = await clientapp.GetAccountAsync(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.GetAccountId());
        if (userAccount != null)
        {
            await clientapp.RemoveAsync(userAccount);
        }
    }


    private static IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    private static IMsalTokenCacheProvider CreateTokenCacheSerializer()
    {
        if (serviceProvider == null)
        {
            // In memory token cache. Other forms of serialization are possible.
            // See https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/asp-net 
            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
        IMsalTokenCacheProvider msalTokenCacheProvider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMsalTokenCacheProvider>();
        return msalTokenCacheProvider;
    }

}
```

Now from webform I am accessing in this way

```
  private async Task method()
    {
        IConfidentialClientApplication app = MsalAppBuilder.BuildConfidentialClientApplication();
        AuthenticationResult result = null;
        var account = await app.GetAccountAsync(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.GetAccountId());
        // var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
        string[] scopes = { "User.Read" };
        result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, account).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        // result = await app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode((scopes).ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```

This accout is always coming null. Am I doing wrong at any place ?

I need token which I need to pass to some other application.
Also, what all the scope I can mention in startup.cs file ?
Like here,     **Scope = BasicSignInScopes + " "+"User.Read",**

I am using Azure AD just for authentication purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The instance of IConfidentialClientApplication is created and attached to an instance of MSALPerUserMemoryTokenCache, which is a custom cache implementation that uses a shared instance of a MemoryCache to cache tokens. When it acquires the access token, MSAL also saves this token in its token cache. When any code in the rest of the project tries to acquire an access token for Microsoft Graph with the same scope (Mail.Read), MSAL will return the cached token.

Learn more [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect#initial-token-acquisition).